# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Computer Graphics' [second attempt at a first successful moderator election](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close. Since there were not enough candidates, we simply appointed the sole candidate:

[image: luser droog]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Comment: Congratulations and thank you for volunteering @luserdroog . Looking forward to moderate this site together with you. :)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks everyone for the warm welcome. I intend to be a permanent fixture in the chatroom. So anyone can feel free to ping me there for anything.

Comment: +10 for being a "permanent fixture in the chatroom" !!! That's what I like to see: approachability and dedication :)